# Copy-item almost works but just missing something obvious

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Below almost works but I am missing something obvious, within the SOURCE folder ODS I have a sub-folder called `Archive`. However when I run the code it appears to not on.ly create another ODS folder in the destination ODS folder but none of the csv files stores in the folder are copies across, I assumed wrongly that -Filter would ensure only the csv's are copied across.

```
## The location/filename where the Logs will be stored
$varfullpath = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\ReferenceData__logfile.txt"        
## The location/filename of the Source to copy from                                    
$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\Source Data\ODS\"
## The location/filename of the Destination to copy to  
$destinationDirectory = "I:\Dev\BI\Projects\Powershell\Test Area\Source Data\ODS\"

## Attempts to copy a file fron Source to Destination and record the event, if the Copy-item fails the script is halted and the error messages are captured in the Log 
## Possibly only 1 error is needed and or applicable, so remove as necessary.
try{
    Copy-item -Force  -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Filter ".csv" -Recurse   -Destination $destinationDirectory  -ErrorAction Stop  
    Write-Log -Message "Copy from $sourceDirectory to $destinationDirectory suceeded"  -path $varfullpath             
}
catch{
    $Error[0] | Write-Log -path $varfullpath                                                                            
    Write-log -Message "Copy from $sourceDirectory to $destinationDirectory Failed"  -Level Error -path $varfullpath     
} 
Start-Process notepad $varfullpath  ## Opens the file immediately for review
```

Comment: I Think you are missing the wildcard.

```Copy-item -Force  -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Filter "*.csv" -Recurse   -Destination $destinationDirectory  -ErrorAction Stop ```

Hope it Helps! BR

Comment: thanks but its copying everything including subfolders AND creating another ODS folder within the existing ODS fold eg csv's appearing in here now  (I:\Dev\BI\Projects\Powershell\Test Area\Source Data\ODS\ODS\Archive). I just want only the csv files in C:\Users\Simon.Evans\Documents\Source Data\ODS\ to be copied into I:\Dev\BI\Projects\Powershell\Test Area\Source Data\ODS\ and nothinbg else.

Comment: currently you are copying the Folder ODS to another Folder ODS. If you want to only copy the files contained perhaps an solution with ```get-childitem``` would be better. There you can define to only take files.
If I have enough time I'll try to provide code

Comment: ```Get-ChildItem -Path '.\Desktop\localtmp\ping\ling ling' -Recurse -File -Filter "*.txt" | Copy-Item -Destination '.\Desktop\ling ling'

```

Comment: This line will copy all files with the ending .txt from the folder ling ling to another folder ling ling

Comment: Thanks Red I had to remove the -Recurse though as was still copying sub files in the Archive subfolder, removing the -Recurse has finally achieved the desired goal, again many thanks

Comment: Haha okay, I shall write a line as answer so that this is answered ;) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discuessed in the comments the solution would be to replace the `try` block with:

```
try{
Get-Childitem -Path $sourceDirectory -File -Filter "*.csv" | Copy-Item -Destination $destinationDirectory -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Hope it helps! BR